# Coupled non-linear ordinary differential equation in R (boundary value) using bvpSolve

Tags: r, numerical-methods, differential-equations, boundary

I am trying to solve the following using R, I need help as I am not familiar with the packages.  I tried to follow the example on page 211 in this book [Solving differential equations in R](https://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-28070-2_9) and I have no luck.

Here is my code

```
library(bvpSolve)

couple_ode <- function(theta, Y,  delta){

  with(as.list(Y), {

  ds <- ((sin(2*omega) + sin(delta)/tan(theta)*cos(2*omega) - sin(delta/tan(theta) - sin(delta)*sin(2*omega))) * s +  (cos(2*omega)*sin(theta) + sin(2*omega)*cos(theta))) / (cos(2*omega) + sin(delta))

  domega <- 0.5* ((cos(delta)^2 - sin(delta)* (sin(2*omega)/tan(theta)+cos(2*omega)+1)*(sin(delta)+1)) * s + (cos(2*omega)*cos(theta)-sin(2*omega)*sin(theta))*sin(delta)+cos(theta)) / (s*sin(delta)*(cos(2*omega)+sin(delta)))  - 1

  return(list(c(ds, domega)))
  })
}

thetas <- seq(from = 0.001, to = pi/4, by = 0.01)
phi_w <- 35/180*pi
delta <- 43/180*pi
y_ini <- c(s = NA, omega = 0)
y_end <- c(s = NA, omega = 0.5*(phi_w+asin(sin(phi_w)/sin(delta))))

Sol <- bvptwp(x = thetas, func = couple_ode, order = c(1,1), par = delta, yini = y_ini, yend = y_end)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
NaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedNaNs producedError in bvpsolver(1, yini, x, func, yend, parms, order, ynames, xguess,  : 
  The Expected No. Of mesh points Exceeds Storage Specifications.
```

I am not sure if the error I get is a numerical hurdle or if my code is wrong.  I think I should give some guess value but do not know how.

Update to original post:
There is a 1/tan(theta) term in the equation and the boundary value start at theta = 0, so it is natural there is an error.  But even after changing it to 0.001.  I still have the same problem.

Comment: Check out Section 3.1 of this, which uses the same function and gives the same error: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bvpSolve/vignettes/bvpSolve.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the direction. It seems I have to use:  Solving a Boundary Value Problem using Continuation. But how can I get a simpler version of a solution and use it as an initial guess for the continuation method?